# errors while laravel 5.6.12 deployment on whm cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, whm

I am deploying a laravel 5.5.12 app on WHM cpanel. 
As per laravel documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation#server-requirements) all the server requirements are okay: 
phpinfo(); results in following:

```
PHP >= 7.1.3
OpenSSL support enabled
PDO support enabled
Multibyte Support   enabled (mbstring)
Tokenizer Support   enabled
XML Support active
Ctype PHP Extension enabled
JSON PHP Extension  enabled
```

i have done following steps (https://crescentke.com/uploading-laravel-5-to-cpanel-server/)

1. uploaded laravel folder to /home/mylaravel (except public and node_modules)
2. uploaded public folder contents  to /home/public_html
3. changed permission of storage, vendor and bootstrap/cache to 777.
4. changed following lines in /home/public_html/index.php

   require **DIR**.'/../mylaravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';

   $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../mylaravel/bootstrap/app.php';
5. changed following line in /home/mylaravel/server.php

   require_once **DIR**.'/public_html/index.php';
6. create a database and added a user to it will full rights, this database, user name are updated in /home/mylaravel/.env file
7. updated the .env file with live server URL
8. for storage folder link inside the public_html, created a php file inside pulic_html will following content and accessed it via URL to create the symlink

   symlink('/home/gfree/go4ree/storage/app/public','/home/gfree/public_html/storage');

NOW at last when i visit the webpage it gives http 500 error. in log file following log is created:

```
[11-Jun-2018 11:37:57 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/gfree/go4ree/vendor/symfony/finder/Comparator/NumberComparator.php on line 42
[11-Jun-2018 11:37:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
```

whats (on earth) left to do?

Comment: As this is a parse error, could you post the code around line 42 in that NumberComparator file?

Comment: There's an issue posted for Laravel 5.6 https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23069. The solution is "use php 7.1" but unsure if that will fix your issue as 5.5 only requires 7.0

Comment: Are you sure you're deploying laravel 5.5 because this issue should not persist if that's true..

Comment: @Niels its following code on line 42: `public function __construct(?string $test)` yes, there is a ? on it but where it comes from?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript yes mate, my bad its 5.6.12... i update the question... sorry for inconvenience... ?

Comment: Then you require php 7.1+

Comment: @IsThisJavascript yes mate... i upgraded the server to php 7.2 and site started working... (you can post it as a answer, so that i can mark it solved)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors appeared because of misunderstanding of laravel version, i have updated the question for any future reference or for some novice like me.

The following artisan command gives you the laravel framework version:

```
php artisan --version
```

visit this page to check the server requirements :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#server-requirements (please note the version)

just make sure the live server met all the prerequisites...
rest of the steps of configuration are already stated in question...